# Nginx : autoindex not working

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

Hello all I'm following a guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QXnk8emzOU and exactly did everything same and I've checked other similar problems such as [nginx autoindex doesn't work](https://serverfault.com/questions/580711/nginx-autoindex-doesnt-work) and [Issues with nginx autoindex](https://serverfault.com/questions/347815/issues-with-nginx-autoindex) .

Configuration file of nginx :

```
server {
        listen 80;                      #says to listen on standard port
        server_name _;                  #the default server
        location / {                    #location is the root of the site
                root /test/a/;          #root is located at /test/a/  
                index index.htm;        #index is for autocomplete
                autoindex on;           #this way files will be autoindexed
        }
}
```

The html files are located at `/test/a`, one is `/test/a/index.htm`, other is `/test/a/outdex.htm`. I see the content of index.htm when I connect to IP of server.

I have recursively changed permissions of all the content for avoiding permission issues earlier as :

`chmod 777 -R /test`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What really happened?

Comment: I just solved the problem and posting the answer, not working mean I type autoindex on but when I entered the site there wasn't any index, there was only the file. It occured because of my deficient knowledge of server block @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 1):

After some error and trial I've reached the solution. My problem actually was trivial. The line which starts with `index` defines files that are going to be used as index, since I have just put there a single file, not a directory, it was the only thing I got, after making changing index as below, I got what I was expecting.

```
server {
        listen 80;                      #says to listen on standard port
        server_name _;                  #the default server
        location / {                    #location is the root of the site
                root /test/a/;          #root is located at /test/a/  
                index test;        #index is for autocomplete
                autoindex on;           #this way files will be autoindexed
        }
}
```

Sources :

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QXnk8emzOU